# Unable to display images in webform in Drupal

Tags: drupal, webforms, drupal-7, image-upload

I have a webform where I would like to allow user to upload the image. I enabled the form component<- file and set the category/Types to jpg,png, gif.

However on clicking upload file, the file is uploaded, but I can only see the link of the image and not the image itself.

I don't have access to the programmable part of website. How to resolve this from admin menu? Thanks in advance.
[image: webform screenshot]